# Atom: Getting git-diff info to display with all grammars like language-gfm

Tags: markdown, atom-editor, git-diff

In the **atom** editor, when some grammars like **language-gfm** or **language-markdown** are selected, the git-diff info is not displaying.

Is there any **atom** configuration that changes this?
I posted an issue on language-markdown in case it comes from the grammar itself [here](https://github.com/burodepeper/language-markdown/issues/169)

As you can see in this TOML screenshot, on the left, git-diff colors the changes since last commit:
(Notably, I added lines (green) and also modified sensitive content (yellow) to display it on this issue)
[image: TOML]

Now for .md files, the git-diff info cannot be seen, even though git-diff "Move to Next Diff" command still works.
[image: Markdown]

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the creator of *language-markdown*, I can now answer my own question, in case anyone gets the same issue.

Basically the *typewriter* package was responsible here.
I had tried to install it to read markdown more easily, and then forgot.

It centers the markdown text and suppresses the **gutter**, which is the part that contains the numbers of lines and git-diff color info.